# Should different multiprocessing.Queue objects be used for different processes when they do not communicate?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, ipc

I am new to multiprocessing and this is a sample code in my program and I was wondering if this is the best practice.

I have set up two processes which do not communicate with each other but I have passes the same `multiprocess.Queue()` object to receive their output. Code sample below:

```
"""Setting up multi-processing"""
    que = Queue()
    processes_list = list()
    process1 = Process(target=lambda q, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4: q.put(readScope(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)),
                      args=(que, scope, numCollects, numChan, startTimeVoltage,))
    processes_list.append(process1)
    process2 = Process(target=lambda q, arg1, arg2, arg3: q.put(readOpsens(arg1, arg2, arg3)),
                      args=(que, ser, ntimes, startTimeOpsens,))
    processes_list.append(process2)

    for process in processes_list:
        process.start()

    for process in processes_list:
        process.join()

    """Data manipulation"""
    voltageData = que.get()
    tempData = que.get()
```

Is this good practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those puts can occur in any order. It is possible for the voltage data to end up in the temp data variable and the temp data in the voltage data variable. So if you want to be sure to get the output of the first process and then the second either tag and sort or use two queues.